# Split a string on the first number occurences

Tags: javascript, regex

I didn't get a suitable regex that enable to split such string:

```
72 g tocirah snaeb 101 sgge 108 g darl 111 spuc loi 32 sinihccuz
```

into strings basing on numbers first occurences like so:

```
72 g tocirah snaeb, 101 sgge, 108 g darl, 111 spuc loi, 32 sinihccuz
```

How can i do that:

```
var str="72 g tocirah snaeb 101 sgge 108 g darl 111 spuc loi 32 sinihccuz";
var regex="/  /";
var result=str.match(regex);
```

Comment: *"basing on numbers first occurences"* What does that mean exactly? `5 foo 4 bar 5 baz` would become `5 foo, 4 bar 5 baz`? What have you tried so far? Splitting is very easily done with [positive lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
var result=str.replace(/ (\d+)/gm, ", $1");
```

**Search pattern**: search an space char followed by one or more numbers and capture the number.

```
 / (\d+)/gm
```

**Replace**: replace by a , followed by the captured number.

```
, $1
```

You can test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/2FwKF/3/

Comment: Hi, the solution above work great, but when the str var is a multiple line, it's not working, i guess the regex is not taking into consideration the line break. How to fix it please?

Comment: Updated: Added the "m" modifier in the regex.

Answer (score 2):

Does this fit ?

```
var str="72 g tocirah snaeb 101 sgge 108 g darl 111 spuc loi 32 sinihccuz";
var regex=/\b(?=\d)/g;

var list = str.split(regex);
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/zT4QY/ (*needs console*)

Comment: I would say that `var regex=/ (?=\d)/` it's a better option: the global flag is useless in that case, and using an actual space you won't have the trailing whitespace.

Comment: or `/\s*(?=\d)/` for that matter.

Comment: both cases are valid.. depends on what exactly the OP tries to accompish .. thanks for chipping in